# How to remove Index?

Tags: python, pandas

**Remove index number in csv, python**

how to remove index number, and replace it with eTime value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# load data from csv
data = pd.read_csv('log_level_out_mini.csv', delimiter=';')
time = data['eTime']
angka = data['eValue']


# Calculating cross-sectional area
diameter = 0.1016  # 4 Inch
A = 1/4 * np.pi * diameter ** 2
print('Luas penampang:', A)

# Calculate Flow Rate
Q = angka * A
print('Flow Rate:', Q)

# Calculate Volume
```

this is the result.

```
                          Time  eValue
0      2017-07-16 00:00:50.017  -0.272
1      2017-07-16 00:01:50.017  -0.272
2      2017-07-16 00:02:50.020  -0.272
3      2017-07-16 00:03:50.003  -0.272
4      2017-07-16 00:04:50.020  -0.272
...                        ...     ...
10032  2017-07-22 23:55:23.803   0.588
10033  2017-07-22 23:56:23.793   0.580
10034  2017-07-22 23:57:23.787   0.583
10035  2017-07-22 23:58:23.797   0.569
10036  2017-07-22 23:59:23.800   0.549
```

how to remove a list index and change to eTime Value?

Comment: Please do not post data or code (as in your «Result») as screenshots but rather as text. Please also provide a reproducible example.

Comment: see if this helps https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Comment: Did you [check the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) about `index_col` parameter of `read_cav`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `index_col` equal to `False`, as per the documentation listed [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> Note: index_col=False can be used to force pandas to not use the first column as the index, e.g. when you have a malformed file with delimiters at the end of each line.

So change:

```
data = pd.read_csv('log_level_out_mini.csv', delimiter=';')
```

to:

```
data = pd.read_csv('log_level_out_mini.csv', delimiter=';', index_col=False)
```